# Spark DataFrame saveAsTable:

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am wondering how one could customize the table settings used by 
`DataFrameWriter#saveAsTable`.

Is there any way to adjust the storage format (e.g. using Avro or ORC),
compression (to use "snappy", etc.) and the location of the table built 
out of the DataFrame?

What I am looking for is the Spark2 `DataFrameWriter#saveAsTable` equivalent of creating a **managed** Hive table with some custom settings you normally pass to the Hive `CREATE TABLE` command as:

- `STORED AS <format>`
- `LOCATION <hdfs_path>`
- `TBLPROPERTIES("orc.compress"="SNAPPY")`

Answer (score 3):

Below is the code to save data in different format like,

1. CSV
2. Parquet
3. Avro
4. orc
5. Json

Also you can adjust different compression while saving data, below is sample code statement for same,

```
df.write
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
    .save("newcars.csv.gz")
```

==============================================================================

```
df.write
    .format("orc")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
    .saveAsTable("tbl_nm")
```

Answer (score 1):

Orc format

```
  df.write.format("orc").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("default.spark1")
```

Parquet format

```
df.write
    .format("parquet")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .save("/home/prashant/spark-data/mental-health-in-tech-survey/parquet-data/")
```